# Adding attachment to cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can I insert an attachment (Word or PDF) in a cell in Excel? Meaning that if I refer to the cell I will refer to the attachment itself.

If i insert an objective and i try to link to it i got error

I refer to it as following (just for example):

=Objective1

We made a sheet include a template for mailbox, everything work fine only we are not able to attache a file in the email.

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are you "attaching" the file and how are you attempting to "link" to it? What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @CharlieRB , in excel we can refer to a cell by typing simple formula = and the cell number, correct? i want a same but to refer to an word document i attached it in the sheet.

Comment: *=Object 1* is not a cell reference. Therefore Excel does not recognize it as a valid link. I don't believe you can link to an embedded object the way you are trying (at least I have not found any).